# how to get an if...then statement to hold my value

Tags: excel, vba

i have 2 cells A1 and B1. A1 is connected to an api data feed so the value is changing practically every second. when its value is >= to B1, how can i hold lets say a value of 1 in cell C1. even if the value in A1 moves above and below B1? i'm trying to hold and store a value of 1 to trigger my worksheet_calculate(). 
     C1 =IF(A1>=B1,1,0)

Comment: How long do you need to latch the value for? You may better off doing this with a UDF or VBA Macro than with a formula.

Comment: i'm trying to hold for 5 minutes at least

Comment: Why not suspend the data feed for five minutes?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a modular variable to keep your value rather than an excel cell, then this value can update an excel cell(s) of your choosing on a frequency of your choice through conditions within worksheet_change or worksheet_calculate

Keep in mind however that worksheet_change and even more so worksheet_calculate fire quite often you may find this becomes a performance bottleneck if the VBA is not gated to only do payload work when absolutely necessary.

An alternative would be to develop a VSTO Add-In to handle your automation cases.

Comment: I was trying to find and alternative to using the worksheet_calculate for that very reason. i wanted a simple way to hold that value to be recalled on maybe a 5 min time interval.

Answer (score 0):

You might have problems with your api not triggering the worksheet calculate anyway in which case the c1 won't get evaluated.

You also might have issues with your api sending a value > x but your system being too slow to pick up that x.

You might want to see if your API offers a =Max( key , since ) , just Max( keyOftoday )

What you might like to do is record the history of a cell, in which case this article might help you. https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-record-a-current-cell-value-that-is-constantly-changing-on-another-Excel-sheet-at-a-specific-point-in-time

At which point it's just a matter of checking if any cell in your recorded range is > than B1